# Warning on Exception-derived class

Tags: java, android, exception

I created my own exception class:

```
public class ApplicationException extends Exception 
{
    public ApplicationException()
    {
        super();
    }

    public ApplicationException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

This warning is shown: "The serializable class ApplicationException does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define a variable named `serialVersionUID` with a type `long`

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```